# Яндекс карта, как высчитать дистанцию в км?

Tags: яндекс-карты

путем манипуляции смог заполучить 2 перемены. У одной координаты и у другой. Вопрос, как использую yandex map api получить расстояния в км от 1 элемента до 2?

Comment: Если по-прямой то есть формула, можно без АПИ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации API Яндекс.Карт есть метод нахождения расстояния между двух точек в метрах - https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/ICoordSystem.html#method_detail__getDistance

Получить из ответа километры будет несложно.